# Не понимаю, как сделать кодировку правильную

Tags: python, кодировка, beautiful-soup

Я работаю с BeautifulSoup на питоне 3.10 в Pycharm, и у меня появляются кракозябры. Я не понимаю, как исправить эту проблему, чтобы в терминале питон мог выводить кириллицу. Из способов в интернете помог только .encode('latin1').decode('cp1251'). Пожалуйста, помогите с этой проблемой. Как избавиться от кракозябр, чтобы они не появлялись? Полный код:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
import sys
import locale
agent = UserAgent()
response = requests.get('https://stroit-kompanii.ru/list/exciton_elektromonta/', params={
    'user-agent': f'{agent.random}'
}).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml').find('h1').text
print(soup.encode('latin1').decode('cp1251'))
print(soup)
print(sys.getdefaultencoding())
print(locale.getpreferredencoding())
print(sys.stdout.encoding)
______________________________________

Exciton, электромонтажная компания
Exciton, ýëåêòðîìîíòàæíàÿ êîìïàíèÿ
utf-8
cp1251
utf-8
```

Comment: `requests.get(...).content.decode('cp1251')`

Comment: response = requests.get().content BeautifulSoup сам разберется с кодировкой.

Comment: Декодировка помогла, спасибо, но как сделать, чтобы такой проблемы вовсе не было?

Comment: @mcorleone никак, это администратор сайта должен на нём неправильные настройки исправлять

Comment: @andreymal Спасибо

Comment: Однако если понадеяться, что кодировка всегда будет прописана в html-коде, то Сергей Ш правильно пишет, что BeautifulSoup сам разберется с кодировкой, и можно просто скармливать в него content без декодирования (однако не факт что это сработает на каких-нибудь других ещё более кривых сайтах)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
response = requests.get('https://stroit-kompanii.ru/list/exciton_elektromonta/'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')
print(soup.text)

Автоматизация инженерных систем
Автоматические ворота "Hoermann"
Автоматические ворота "ZAIGER"
Автоматические ворота, двери
Агентства недвижимости
```

Comment: Спасибо, это решение проще, оно помогло